# Multiple 404 error pages using Python (Flask)

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

Is it possible to serve multiple 404 pages in python using flask?

Currently I have this in my views.py file:

```
@application.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return render_template('errorpages/404.html'), 404
```

Is it manageable to serve, for example, three random 404 pages instead of just one? How?

Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want your server to randomly pick one of three 404 pages to serve then you could do something like this:

```
import random

@application.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return render_template(
        'errorpages/404_{}.html'.format(random.randint(0, 3)) ), 404
```

Where your pages are `errorpages/404_1.html`, `errorpages/404_2.html` and `errorpages/404_3.html`

Or if you wanted which page got served to depend on a condition, your code would look something like this:

```
@application.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    if condition:
        return render_template('errorpages/404_1.html'), 404
    return render_template('errorpages/404.html'), 404
```